# Определить попадание точки в круг

Tags: google-maps-api, gis, mysql

Добрый день.
В базе хранятся координаты точки (тип float) из google-maps. Нужно при получении подобных координат определить какие хранящиеся в базе точки попадают в круг полученной точки.
Т.е. есть координата в базе 5, 5. Поступает координата 6, 6. Есть радиус определенны (скажем 5 метров), нужно узнать - попадает ли 6, 6 в круг.
Вопрос вроде не сложный, но сообразить не могу как правильно все это рассчитать

Comment: а если это не окружность а площадь

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вам можно воспользоваться следующим условием:

```
(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 <= R^2
```

где x и y  - координаты вашей точки, x0 и y0 - координаты центра окружности, R - радиус окружности, ^2 - возведение в квадрат. Если условие выполняется, то точка находится внутри (или на окружности, в случае равенства левой и правой частей). Если не выполняется, то точка вне окружности.

Необходимое уточнение - это будет работать в случае небольших радиусов (до нескольких километров). В случае же окружностей с большими радиусами допущение о том, что поверхность плоская станет неверным - нужно будет принимать во внимание кривизну поверхности Земли и вносить коррективы с учетом пространственной геометрии

Comment: А в квадрат только x возводим?
Радиус в метрах или в км идет,по идеи для гео-точек в км?

Comment: Смотрите внимательнее, x в квадрат не возводится. В квадрат возводятся слагаемые из левой части и правая часть условия.  Размерность радиуса значения не имеет - хоть метры, хоть километры, хоть морские мили. только вот не забудьте про уточнение, указанное в конце ответа, это может быть важно

Comment: Спасибо.
Нашел еще такой вариант - 
select *
WHERE latitude BETWEEN (@lan - 100 * 0.1988) AND (@lan + @r * 0.1988 / 2)
AND longitude BETWEEN (@lng - 100 * 0.1988) AND (@lng + @r * 0.1988 / 2)
если кому-то понадобится, @lan и @lng - координаты точки, @r - радиус в метрах (0,1988 переводит в радианы)